# How to use loops to limit the documents in a html table column column (5 in col 1, 5 in col 2, 5 in col3 ) jsp

Tags: jsp

I need the from the controller to the JSP page where I have a table
 inserted all the data coming from Resultset to the of that table.
Only Allowed 15 documents in the table.

I want to  just limit the data to 5 in each column (5 in col 1, 5 in col 2, 5 in col3).

```
record1     record6     record11  
record2     record7     record12  
record3     record8     record13  
record4     record9     record14  
record5     record10    record15
```

Comment: Why not limiting the data to 15 entries?

Comment: i need first 15 documents each colum have only 5 entries. total 3 columes 15 documents